# How to download part of a site with httrack including assets?

Tags: httrack

I would like to download `http://www.example.com/foobar` and every HTML page linked from there, where the URL starts with `http://www.example.com/foobar`. I would like to download every non-HTML asset linked as well, regardless of their path. I tried:

```
httrack http://www.example.com/foobar -mime:text/html +http://www.example.com/foobar*
```

and also added:

```
+http://www.example.com/foobar +http://www.example.com/foobar/*
```

but this resulted in no pages downloaded whatsoever.

Comment: Why did you add `-mime:text/html`? This says to ignore HTML files, and without them there are no links and nothing to download.

Comment: Well, I hoped the ` +http://www.example.com/foobar*` will override it. The problem is `http://www.example.com/foobar` is a HTML page, `http://www.example.com/foobar/baz` is another and so on. I do not know how to tell httrack to download these + assets anywhere.

Comment: Without the `mime` part, do you get anything?

Comment: Well, I either don't get assets if I try `-*` instead (because they are not under `/foobar`) or it tries to download the entire site.

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Linux but why would that matter...? I quote my arguments containing asterisks even if the question doesn't contain it (sorry for that). I wish I could delete this question now where I am thought an idiot after using Linux for a quarter century :/ I already solved it with wget, now it just sits there perhaps for posterity.

Comment: You will be able to delete the post once the bounty is gone, awarded or elapsed.

Comment: Why not to use wget -r ?

Comment: @JoseManuelGomezAlvarez: The poster already solved the problem using wget. Nothing left to do here.

Comment: try using developer tools (browser) to write a custom console command.

Answer (score 1):

I still have no idea how to do this with httrack (although I really would like to understand how httrack filters work but apparently that's not going to happen, everyone just repeats the same useless manual page) but I was able to solve my problem with wget although not as asked. See, I actually know where the assets reside and so I was able to do this:

```
wget -rkpEI foobar/,assetpath1/,assetpath2/ https://www.example.com/foobar
```

This worked. More or less. To be fair, I later needed to loop every file and redownload them one by one -- the `-k` option of `wget` when downloading a single file makes every link an absolute URL which is really helpful for later `sed` work.